# Problemas com Json a receber valor interior

Tags: android

Tenho este código que por sua vez o que faz é ir buscar um id a base de dados mas o primeiro valor que ele vai buscar é 0 passado 1 segundo ele vai buscar o valor correto testei com um *output* de texto .

Exemplo Primeiro id que ele vai buscar: 0

Após 1 segundo fica com id: 33

Clico novamente para obter um id próximo ou seja 34 ele vai buscar: 33

Passado 1 segundo fico com id :34

Usei um *dialog* para tentar solucionar o problema mas não resolveu.

```
 JSONObject jsa = null;
    try {
        jsa = new JSONObject(myJSON);


        favId = jsa.getInt("FavoritoId");



    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Aonde você guarda essa variável favId ? creio que tem que resetar ela

Comment: Nossa, quase não entendi nada! O problema é mesmo no Json ou da base de onde esta vindo esse id?